# Cannot Access Kickstart.php

Tags: joomla, localhost, filezilla

Let me explain you the scenario upto now..

Been a newbie to Joomla I managed to build my own website using Joomla CMS in my computers localhost.

Then after the completion of the site, I wanted to upload my Local Joomla Site to a GoDaddy Server / Hosting Account..

Thanks to Google I found the below mentioned tutorial,
http://zensamarketing.com/2009/07/how-to-use-joomlapack-and-kickstart-to-upload-your-local-joomla-site-to-a-godaddy-server-hosting-account/

So far I completed up to the 7th step, But I'm stuck at the step 08.

I'm using Filezilla as my FTP client, Using that I uploaded the files as per the guided on step 07 and when I try to access www.mysitename.com/kickstart.php, it is giving me the below error,

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /kickstart.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How can I set permission... Please explain in a non technical way..

Thank you so much in advance smile

Answer (score 0):

Using FileZilla, you could set the permissions (CHMOD) of kickstart.php to 777.

Right click on the file, file attributes.  In the window that opens, you'll be able to make adjustments there.

Is this Windows or Unix hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Try changing your browser. First i used Firefox dev edition and got errors. Then used IE (was not any better) then Vivaldi and it worked.